# Collapse Text in Flex Without specifying width or flex-basis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to have a horizontal menu that will collapse text with ellipsis, but doesn't expand to full width. I've gotten it to work fine, except for IE. If I set width or flex-basis, it will work, but then it's not set based on content size anymore. Does anyone have any tips on a workaround? I've googled around for a fix, but nothing I've tried so far has been successful.

```css
html,body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  background: #0088ff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #bbccff;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 0;
}
ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #77aaff;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Should collapse</h2>
<ul>
  <li style='flex-shrink:1'><a>Test</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:11'><a>Test Medium</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:13'><a>Test A Longer Phrase</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Should not expand</h2>
<ul>
  <li style='flex-shrink:1'><a>Test</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:11'><a>Test Medium</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Posted an answer though wanted also to ask, _what do you think (or expect) your `flex-shrink` does in your samples_?

Comment: In Chrome, it makes the li shrink so that they all fit the parent container. It also works in edge, so this is an IE bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to make IE behave is to add `display: flex` to the `li` so it becomes a flex container.

```css
html,body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  background: #0088ff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #bbccff;
  /*                        not needed as it is their default
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  */
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 0;
  display: flex;            /*  fix for IE  */
}
ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #77aaff;
}
ul li a {
  /* display: block;            not needed  */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Should collapse</h2>
<ul>
  <li style='flex-shrink:1'><a>Test</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:11'><a>Test Medium</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:13'><a>Test A Longer Phrase</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Should not expand</h2>
<ul>
  <li style='flex-shrink:1'><a>Test</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:11'><a>Test Medium</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

Another is to add `overflow: hidden` to the `li`.

```css
html,body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  background: #0088ff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #bbccff;
  /*                        not needed as it is their default
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  */
  text-align: center;
  /* min-width: 0;          not needed when overflow:hidden is used  */
  overflow: hidden;         /*  fix for IE  */
}
ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background: #77aaff;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Should collapse</h2>
<ul>
  <li style='flex-shrink:1'><a>Test</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:11'><a>Test Medium</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:13'><a>Test A Longer Phrase</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
  <h2>Should not expand</h2>
<ul>
  <li style='flex-shrink:1'><a>Test</a></li>
  <li style='flex-shrink:11'><a>Test Medium</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is how you exterminate the bugs in IE. Really nice.

Comment: That led me in the right direction. My example didn't have everything. The <a> in my actual code has a child for text and then a close button, and sometimes a `::before` element), but if I have either `display: flex` or `display:block;overflow:hidden;` all the way down, then it eventually works.

Comment: @bradlis7 That sounds great, and is correct. One need to explicit set it to all descendants or else it won't work.